# Is there a name for this mis-application of marginal distributions?

Tags: marginal-distribution, marketing

Recently I was shown some market research that was more or less equivalent to the following:

- 50% of the population is female
- 50% of the population is blonde
- therefore, our new hair dye for blonde women could appeal to 50% of the population.

I was about to mumble something about marginal distributions, but is there a name for this kind of reasoning? Ideally, something that non-statisticians could relate to?

Comment: There would also be 25% conclusion as well (=50% of 50%) which is the "independence" assumption

Comment: I don't know a pithy name for it, but you could probably demonstrate the fallacy with a Venn diagram

Comment: I would say that the above is just a non sequitur rather than a cognitive bias.

Comment: The weasel word "could" means it's not  actually a reasoning error until you introduce the additional fact that gender and hair color are not associated in anything like the way that would be needed for that fact to hold (i.e. non-blonde females are a very substantial fraction of the population). However, there's also no reason whatever to think that the conclusion has any correspondence to reality. I agree with Ceki -- it's nearer to a *non sequitur*.

Answer (score 1):

Denote (in proportions), $F$ for female and $nF$ for "non-female", $B$ for "blonde" and $nB$ for "non-blonde". The information

- 50% of the population is female
- 50% of the population is blonde

permits us only to write

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r|}
  \hline                       
     & \text {B} & \text{nB} &\Sigma \\
  \hline 
  \hline                       
  F &   &   & 0.5 \\
  \hline                     
nF &   &   & 0.5 \\
\hline
\Sigma & 0.5 & 0.5 & 1 \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

The "conclusion" from this information

- therefore, our new hair dye for blonde women could appeal to 50% of the population.

appears to only imply that the following *may* hold:

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r|}
  \hline                       
     & \text {B} & \text{nB} &\Sigma \\
  \hline 
  \hline                       
  F & 0.5  &   & 0.5 \\
  \hline                     
nF &   &   & 0.5 \\
\hline
\Sigma & 0.5 & 0.5 & 1 \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

But hey, this leads to a *unique* full filling of the table: the "conclusion" *necessarily implies* that

\begin{array}{| r | r | r | r|}
  \hline                       
     & \text {B} & \text{nB} &\Sigma \\
  \hline 
  \hline                       
  F & 0.5  & 0.0  & 0.5 \\
  \hline                     
nF &  0.0 & 0.5  & 0.5 \\
\hline
\Sigma & 0.5 & 0.5 & 1 \\
  \hline  
\end{array}

In other words: in order for it to be possible that our new hair dye for blonde women can appeal to $50\%$ of the population (given the information we have on it), it **must be the case** that

- **All females are blonde**

  **and also** that
- **All non-females are non-blonde**

I believe simple arithmetic is something that non-statisticians can relate to.